# ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying <> integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

We have a status (CustomerStatus Enum) column in the customer table and need to populate user which is not delete. is it required any type case for enum ?
list("status NOT IN(?1)", CustomerStatus.DELETE)

during execution I got below error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying <> integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 404
```

```
2021-10-23 11:14:02,713 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) HTTP Request to /api/testplans?userId=2680912425326220290 failed, error id: 4f90f95d-f263-42d3-8efe-37330291a3b4-1: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:135)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:90)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1626)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.CommonPanacheQueryImpl.list(CommonPanacheQueryImpl.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.runtime.PanacheQueryImpl.list(PanacheQueryImpl.java:149)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.runtime.JpaOperations.list(JpaOperations.java:24)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.runtime.JpaOperations.list(JpaOperations.java:10)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.list(AbstractJpaOperations.java:233)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.repositories.TestPlanRepository.list(TestPlanRepository.java)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.repositories.TestPlanRepository_Subclass.list$$superforward1(TestPlanRepository_Subclass.zig:2124)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.repositories.TestPlanRepository_Subclass$$function$$22.apply(TestPlanRepository_Subclass$$function$$22.zig:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.repositories.TestPlanRepository_Subclass.list(TestPlanRepository_Subclass.zig:4792)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.repositories.TestPlanRepository.findByUserId(TestPlanRepository.java:20)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.repositories.TestPlanRepository_Subclass.findByUserId$$superforward1(TestPlanRepository_Subclass.zig:2185)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.repositories.TestPlanRepository_Subclass$$function$$26.apply(TestPlanRepository_Subclass$$function$$26.zig:33)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.repositories.TestPlanRepository_Subclass.findByUserId(TestPlanRepository_Subclass.zig:5158)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.repositories.TestPlanRepository_ClientProxy.findByUserId(TestPlanRepository_ClientProxy.zig:1087)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.processors.TestPlanProcessorImpl.getTestplans(TestPlanProcessorImpl.java:46)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.processors.TestPlanProcessorImpl_Subclass.getTestplans$$superforward1(TestPlanProcessorImpl_Subclass.zig:466)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.processors.TestPlanProcessorImpl_Subclass$$function$$9.apply(TestPlanProcessorImpl_Subclass$$function$$9.zig:33)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.processors.TestPlanProcessorImpl_Subclass.getTestplans(TestPlanProcessorImpl_Subclass.zig:1281)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.processors.TestPlanProcessorImpl.processorGetTestplans(TestPlanProcessorImpl.java:41)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.processors.TestPlanProcessorImpl_Subclass.processorGetTestplans$$superforward1(TestPlanProcessorImpl_Subclass.zig:481)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.processors.TestPlanProcessorImpl_Subclass$$function$$10.apply(TestPlanProcessorImpl_Subclass$$function$$10.zig:33)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.processors.TestPlanProcessorImpl_Subclass.processorGetTestplans(TestPlanProcessorImpl_Subclass.zig:1373)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.processors.TestPlanProcessorImpl_ClientProxy.processorGetTestplans(TestPlanProcessorImpl_ClientProxy.zig:252)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.TestplanServiceImpl.getTestplans(TestplanServiceImpl.java:60)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.TestplanServiceImpl_Subclass.getTestplans$$superforward1(TestplanServiceImpl_Subclass.zig:309)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.TestplanServiceImpl_Subclass$$function$$6.apply(TestplanServiceImpl_Subclass$$function$$6.zig:33)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.TestplanServiceImpl_Subclass.getTestplans(TestplanServiceImpl_Subclass.zig:884)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.services.testplan.TestplanServiceImpl_ClientProxy.getTestplans(TestplanServiceImpl_ClientProxy.zig:129)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.resources.testplan.TestplanResource.getTestplans(TestplanResource.java:50)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.resources.testplan.TestplanResource_Subclass.getTestplans$$superforward1(TestplanResource_Subclass.zig:475)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.resources.testplan.TestplanResource_Subclass$$function$$6.apply(TestplanResource_Subclass$$function$$6.zig:33)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.interceptor.AbstractMethodValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(AbstractMethodValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.jaxrs.JaxrsEndPointValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(JaxrsEndPointValidationInterceptor.java:35)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.jaxrs.JaxrsEndPointValidationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(JaxrsEndPointValidationInterceptor_Bean.zig:392)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:50)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at cana.codelessautomation.api.resources.testplan.TestplanResource_Subclass.getTestplans(TestplanResource_Subclass.zig:1062)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1443)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
    ... 110 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying <> integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 404
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2552)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:322)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
    at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 125 more
```

Comment: Please take the time to improve the question. Describe what you want to achieve, provide a more complete code example, describe what you expect to happen and what happens instead. We don't know what "is not working" means (compile time error, run-time error, in correct result). We don't know what type *status* is.

Comment: sorry for that @Codo. added more details.

Comment: found issue and fixed. enum get saved in database as int not string. after adding 
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) and it's worked like champ